# App Changes are not visible on redeployment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using `create-react-app` for my website. I created the website and deployed it to `Netlify` and opened it in the browser(Normal window) and everything works fine. Now I made some changes in my app, I build the app again using `yarn build` and redeployed to `Netlify`. Now when I open the app in the normal window again, the app changes are not visible. When I open the app in Incognito, I can see my changes. I understand its because of history and cache of the browser but how to let the browser know that there have been some changes in my app and it needs to load my new website. Unfortunately I have no knowledge of `SSR`, is it possible to do it from the client side itself. I have enabled service worker for PWA supports this the cause of issue and how to overcome it??

Comment: Usually, React set different `filenames` to the resources to avoid `cached resource`,  when you build it for the production. This will never happen in the production build. Anyways https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk will help you...

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I have enabled service worker for PWA support, is this the cause of issue and if yes do you know how to overcome it??

Comment: It may cause the issue, I am not a react developer, Refer this,
https://medium.com/@addyosmani/progressive-web-apps-with-react-js-part-3-offline-support-and-network-resilience-c84db889162c